# Variable goes undefined after assignement AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, getjson

I'm using $http.get method to get objects from a json file. It puts them in the data variable as an array of objects. The first time I try to use the variables contained in the objects to initialize a marker it works, but then the variables disappear, and the console gives me "TypeError: Cannot set property 'center' of undefined" on the line where I try to overwrite the .center value, and even the alert gives nothing.

```
var mapOptions =
{
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    zoom: 16,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), mapOptions);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(0, 0),
    map: map,
    title: 'Uluru (Ayers Rock)'
});

$http.get("buses/buses.json").success(function(data){
    console.log(angular.isArray(data));
    marker.position = new google.maps.LatLng(data[1].lat, data[1].lon);
    alert(data[1].lon);
    map.mapOptions.center = marker.position;
    alert(data[1].lon);
});
```

Comment: We are going to need more of the code. For example we don't see where map is defined and what scope this entire thing is in.

Comment: Where are you defining map.mapOptions?

Comment: added the extra code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't if be `map.setCenter(marker.position);`?

Comment: it works now, and the second alert gives me result. I still don't understand how that happened, also going to fix the code, I copy pasted in a hurry and forgot to clean it up a little bit.

Comment: Yeah, and I don't know why

Comment: I think it's simply because this is how you set the map center using google maps API

Comment: Ok thanks, and thanks to whoever edited my post, i was going to do it myself but ty